# Why does empty returns 1/1/1900?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have store date as "" but it returns `1/1/1900` I have tried  Convert(varchar,PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoDOB, 106) as PersonalInfoDOB, but return `1/1/1900`

Comment: what it should return instead of 1/1/1900?

Comment: why are you not storing it as a datetime?

Comment: @Lashane I want an empty string, i tried NULLIF but nothing works,

Comment: @Fallenreaper it is,

Comment: @Stacky Flowy you shouldn't want empty strings to represent "No Date", you should want NULL to represent "No Date".

Comment: `PersonalInfoDOB` is of char type? If this is true, so you try to convert a char type to char type? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

SQL can only return 1 datatype in a given column. That means if you have an empty string returned in a datetime column it will perform an implicit cast to datetime. When dealing with datetime there is actually two implicit conversions happening here. The first is to implicitly cast the value to an int and an empty string implicitly cast to an int is 0. Then the int is cast to a datetime and the int value 0 will be cast to 1900-01-01 as a datetime.

Comment: Implicit cast rules, [small demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424262) for non believers. [Type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) `VARCHAR(...) -> INT -> DATETIME` :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to store it as NULL not as ""
datetime is not compatible with string ("")